# Why am I getting an empty output file in my java code for USACO?

Tags: java, io

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class palsquare {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //File file = new File("palsquare.in");
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("palsquare.in"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("palsquare.out")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
        int base = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        for(int i = 1; i < 300; i++){
            String e = Integer.toString(i * i);
            String t = convertFromBaseToBase(e, 10, base);
            if(t.equals(revStr(t))){
                out.println(i + " " + t);
            }
        }

    }
    public static String convertFromBaseToBase(String str, int fromBase, int toBase) {
        return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str, fromBase), toBase);
    }
    public static String revStr(String str){
        String revStr = "";
        for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            revStr = revStr + str.charAt(i);
        }
        return revStr;
    }
}
```

I am confused as to why my code is not working. The trainer for USACO responds to my submission by saying that it returned a blank file but on my computer it works when using Scanner and I dont know how to use this on my computer. I am only 12 and still learning. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to `close()` the `Writer` (which would also `flush()` the contents of the buffer to the file) after writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is not `flush()` operation that pushes the content to the file. This can be done with `.flush()` or `.close()`. Using the nice `Closeable` interface you can (and this allows to catch exception) :

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("palsquare.in"));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("palsquare.out")))) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
    int base = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    for (int i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
        String e = Integer.toString(i * i);
        String t = convertFromBaseToBase(e, 10, base);
        if (t.equals(revStr(t))) {
            out.println(i + " " + t);
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will automatically close the in/out streams and call the flush() on the output ones

Comment: This assumes OP uses Java 7+ (which could well be the case), but it's nice to mention that requirement in the answer.

Comment: @Vasan I think that now we can't write answer that relies on code that is like "no more than Java 7) It would be to hard^^

Comment: @Vasan: Java 7 has been release 8 years ago and hasn't seen free updates for 5 years now. I think it's reasonable to assume that anyone who starts learning Java now is at least up to that level. And if they are not they need to run away *fast* from whatever they use to learn.